# Get only the right rows in Excel files with EPPlus.DataExtractor

Tags: c#, uwp, epplus

I'm getting data from Excel files with the `EPPlus.DataExtractor` library:

```cs
private static async Task addComptInformation(string codePoste, Poste currentPoste)
{
    var stream = await comptFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    using (var p = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
        // get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        var endRow = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

        var data = worksheet.Extract<Compteur>()
        .WithProperty(c => c.TablRL, "A")//
        .WithProperty(c => c.Charge, "A")//
        .WithProperty(c => c.Energie, "A")//
        .WithProperty(c => c.FactMult, "W")
        .WithProperty(c => c.Type, "U")
        .WithProperty(c => c.NumSerie, "T")
        .WithProperty(c => c.CodePoste, "C")
        .GetData(5, endRow).ToList();

        foreach (Compteur c1 in data)
        {
            if (c1.CodePoste != null && c1.CodePoste.Equals(codePoste))
            {
                currentPoste.Compteurs.Add(c1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I get every single line of my Excel file and transform it to a list of `Compteur` objects, after that I'm using that list to keep only a few instances matching the right `CodePoste`.

It's not really optimized and I have no clue how to do it better.

Is there a way to just retrieve the right rows in the Excel files and only transform that rows into a `Compteur` object ?

Comment: I'm afraid there is not much you can do to "optimize" it with the DataExtractor library. In terms of code, you can make usage of the lazy evaluation with linq to filter only the elements you want before obtaining the list for it. So you would save `.GetData(5, endRow).Where(c => c != null && c.CodePoste.Equals(codePoste)).ToList()`, if you do that, your `data` will have only what you need, you can then just do a `currentPoste.Compteurs.AddRange(data)`

Comment: I have noticed that you're extracting the `A` column to 3 different properties, is that intentional?

Comment: @IPValverde - You're the author of the library, correct? I was digging into the source code looking for other methods, but I'm 100% certain I won't find anything you don't know about.

Comment: Yeah, I'm the author of that library. Unfortunately the library is not as well documented as I would like. The library has no particular feature for filtering data, since it returns a `IEnumerable` the consumer can just filter the data. Even though I'm pretty sure there is such filtering feature, I have to say that I'm a bit rusty regarding the set of features in that library, it wouldn't surprise me if someone finds a feature or method that I don't remember :)

Comment: I'll use the Linq statement that's a good idea.
For the columns, yeah it's normal.
Do you know if there is any way to do what I want with only the EPPlus library ?